# ArcGIS util failed to load when trying to create map from webmap API version 4.11

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

Here are my requires

```
    require([
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/WebMap",
        "esri/config",
        "esri/arcgis/utils"
    ],
    function (MapView, WebMap, esriConfig, arcgisUtils)
```

Here are my links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/"></script>
```

I am retrieving a webmap and I want to create a map. I do this with the following lines of code.

```
    /**
     * Purpose: Create a new map object from the webmap retrieved online
     */
    function createMap(arcgisUtils) {
        mapDeferred = arcgisUtils.createMap(webmap, "map", {
            mapOptions: {
                slider: true
            }
        });

        /**
        * Purpose: Assign map once a response is retrieved
        *
        * @param response
        */
        mapDeferred.then(function (response) {
            map = response.map;

            /* EVENTS */
            map.on("load", function () {
                map.on("click", updateLongitudeLatitude);
            });

            /* TODO
              Retrieve layers
              Figure out filter layers
              Access pop up window
            */
        });

    }
```

My problem is the map isn't loading in google chrome. I looked at the error message and it said that arcgis utils failed to load. So I think maybe arcgis utils is not supported in 4.11? If not then how could I create a map object from a webmap that I retrieve. Thanks in advance.

Error message:

Error: scriptError: https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/arcgis/utils.js

Failed to load resource

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use `esri/arcgis/utils` which is [from the 3.x version of the API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/esri.arcgis.utils-amd.html#createmap), but you are loading version 4.11 (`<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/ ...`). I would encourage you to stick with the 4.x version of the api, but change your code to use [esri/WebMap](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-WebMap.html) instead. [Full example here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/webmap-basic/index.html).